# Simplifying Boolean $ab+c+(abc)'+bc+c'b$ and $xy+xz+(yz+yz')'$

Tags: logic, boolean-algebra

I have these two equations
$$ab +c + (abc)' + bc + c'b$$
$$xy + xz + (yz + yz')'$$
and need to simplify both. Addition means $\lor$, multiplication means $\land$ and the prime means $\neg$.

I have been reading that I have to follow certain rules but I can't get my head arount it. Can somebody help show me how to simplify both?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: How is this Boolean Algebra? Is the prime symbol meant to be a negation? Can you explain your notation please

Comment: Try to compare the rules to those of the usual arithmetic, e.g. does the distributive property $a(b+c)=ab +ac$ work the same?, which rules are different?...

Comment: according to the material that i am reading this is the Canonical normal form. but i think that the simplification needs to be done after the equal sign. i am going to edited now

Comment: @lioness99a I added the explanation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$ab+c+(abc)'+bc+c'b$$
Use De Morgan's law on $(abc)'$:
$$=ab+c+a'+b'+c'+bc+c'b$$
Since $x+x'=1$:
$$=ab+1+a'+b'+bc+c'b$$
This is a disjunction of terms, one of which is a 1, so the whole thing immediately reduces to **1**.

---

$$xy+xz+(yz+yz')'$$
Collect $y$ in $(yz+yz')'$, then use $x+x'=1$:
$$=xy+xz+y'$$
Distribute $\lor$ over $\land$ in $xy+y'$, then use $x+x'=1$ (again):
$$=x+y'+xz$$
$x$ absorbs $xz$:
$$=x+y'$$
This is the most simplified form.

Comment: i undersetood perfectly! i think i know where to apply the laws now